Right adjoint of the forgetful functor from involution algebras
This question comes from Harold Simmons Introduction to Category Theory.
The author defines an involution algebra to be a set together with an involution. We will write the involution $a^\circ$, so $\circ$ is a function from $A$ to $A$ with $a^{\circ \circ} = a$. He then claims that the forgetful functor has a right adjoint given by $\Pi(X) = X \times X$ with the involution $(x_1, x_2)^\circ = (x_2, x_1)$, and asks the reader to construct the bijections $f \to f^*$ and $g \to g_*$.
I'm confused on how to construct $f^*$: we are given a morphism of involution algebras from $A$ to $X \times X$, so we have $f(a) = (x_1, x_2)$, but we need to produce a map of sets into $X$. There is a sort of hint to remember that $f$ is a morphism.
This tells us that $f(a^\circ) = f(a)^\circ = (x_2, x_1)$, but it seems that we would need $f(a)$ to be on the diagonal in order to make a choice of which $x_i$ is the image of $f^*(a)$, and I don't see how being a morphism of involution algebras guarantees this.
Any help is appreciated!

I think you'll probably want to just take the set map $A \to X$, $a \mapsto \pi_1(f(a)) = x_1$.  (The fact that you have a morphism of involution algebras will presumably come into play when you show that one of the compositions is the identity: that if you take $f \in \operatorname{Hom}{\mathsf{InvAlg}}(A, U(X))$, convert to a morphism in $\operatorname{Hom}{\mathsf{Set}}(\Pi(A), X)$, and then convert to a morphism in $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{InvAlg}}(A, U(X))$ again, you get back $f$.)

Just let $f^$ be $\pi_1 \circ f$, where $\pi_1$ is the first projection map (i.e., if $f(a)=(x_1, x_2)$, then $f^(a)=x_1$). For the inverse bijection, let $g_*(a)$ be $(g(a), g(a^{\circ}))$.

(Incidentally, it's easy to see that the category of involution algebras is equivalent to the category of $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$-sets, so if you're familiar with the more general adjunction for $G$-sets where $G$ is a group, that might be helpful.  Though if not, maybe this example can be helpful in reverse as a lead-in to the more general construction.)

The category of involution algebras could be seen as a category of coalgebras. Namely, the functor $\Pi(X)=X \times X$ could be seen as a comonad with $\epsilon_X:\Pi(X) \to X$ given by the first projection map and $\delta_X:\Pi(X) \to \Pi(\Pi(X))$ given by $\delta_X(x_1, x_2)=((x_1, x_2), (x_2, x_1))$. The category of involution algebras would then just be the category of coalgebras for that comanad.

If you're just starting out with universal constructions and adjoint functors, then a useful reference might be George Bergman's category theory notes at https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/3.4.pdf .  In particular, the philosophy of how to discover such constructions given on page 67 of those notes.  For the case of a right adjoint, to paraphrase the question given there: "Given an involution algebra $A$ and a set map $U(A) \to X$, for an element $a \in A$, what data about $a$ can one describe in terms of $X$ and the involution algebra structure on $A$?"

The answer to that question ends up being: given $g : U(A) \to X$, and an element $A \in A$, we have the data of $g(a) \in X$ and $g(a^\circ) \in X$.  And if we have $g(a) = x_1 \in X$, $g(a^\circ) = x_2 \in X$, then we can also see what the data corresponding to $a^\circ$ are: $g(a^\circ) = x_2$ and $g((a^\circ)^\circ) = g(a) = x_1$.  That's where the construction of $\Pi(X) = X \times X$ and the given involution on $\Pi(X)$ could be discovered from; and the process of "extracting data" goes into the part mentioned by Geoffrey Tang's comment, $g_*(a) = (g(a), g(a^\circ))$.

For each involution algebra, let $i_A\colon A\to A$ be the set-function $a\mapsto a^\circ$.  It is claimed there is a natural correspondence of set-functions $g\colon A\to X$ from an involution algebra $A$ to involution algebra homomorphisms $f\colon A\to X\times X$.
By definition an involution algebra homomorphism $f\colon A\to X\times X$ is a pair $(f_0,f_1)$ of set-functions $f_i\colon A\to X$ such that $f_i\circ i_A=f_{1-i}$.
Defining $f^*=f_0$ or $f^*=f_1$ both give a natural correspondences with respective inverse $g_*=(g,g\circ i_A)$ or $g_*=(g\circ i_A,g)$.
